# Kendo Grid Aggregate Sum Displaying Empty Footer

Tags: .net, razor, kendo-grid

I am getting a footer with 0 value from this code. Anyone knows why please?

Thanks

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).HtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "kendoGrid"}) _
        .Name("ExternalMailInvDetailsGrid") _
        .Columns(Sub(c)
                         c.Bound(Function(p) p.Description)
                         c.Bound(Function(p) p.Quantity)
                         c.Bound(Function(p) p.UnitPrice)
                         c.Bound(Function(p) p.TotalPrice)
                         c.Bound(Function(p) p.GSTPrice).ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#")

                 End Sub) _
                              .Pageable() _
                              .Selectable(Sub(sel)
                                                  sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
                                          End Sub) _
.Scrollable() _
.DataSource(Sub(c)
                    c.Ajax() _
                    .PageSize(8) _
                    .Aggregates(Sub(agg)
                                        'agg.Add(Function(p) p.TotalPrice).Sum()
                                        agg.Add(Function(p) p.GSTPrice).Sum()

                                End Sub) _
                    '.Group(Sub(g)
                    '             g.Add(Function(p) p.TotalPrice)
                    '       End Sub)
            End Sub)
)
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding another line of code: `serveroperation(false)` this code somehow magically works now.

I have also received a response from Telerik team and they reckon if i am binding kendo grid with the server side data, then i should use footertemplate instead of clientfootertemplate. Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik, its the answer by the person who asked the question. :)

Comment: Ah, my bad. removing flag.

Comment: what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to define the footer template in .ClientFooterTemplate in columns

you may want to refer to the kendo demo website

Comment: thanks for replying. i had a look and changed the clientgroupfootertemplate to clientfootertemplate but the total sum is still 0 for some reason. any more ideas please?

Comment: I didn't see any read action from the datasource though. If you're somehow reading the data from datasource, make sure it's something like IEnumerable<> instead of DataTable

Comment: instead of having the read action in the data source, i have jquery function which calls the action and the controller and then bind the data.

Comment: then i guess you have to define the aggregates function in that jquery function instead of this one. That both datasource and aggregates have to be together.